# How to find the commands that I need in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab has many useful functions for many different things. It's impossible know the name of each function. Most of the time I know what the function I need must do but I don't know the name of that function into Matlab. Then I can't have help of the help options of the Matlab. So many times I need internet for search the name of the matlab function name.

I would like know a function, like `help | findstr /i <string>` of cmd or `apropos <string>` of Scilab and bash terminals, for search a string through local documentation into the matlab.

Comment: If your issue is searching through offline documentation, you can use [`doc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/doc.html)

Comment: Is doc the same of help? If so, I would need the name of the function. But I didn't know the name.

Comment: Not same as `help` but even better. It's  just like the online documentation and you can search for any string using it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lookfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lookfor.html) to search the local documentation. This will search the documentation of both built-ins as well as any user-defined functions that are on your path.

By default, it will search only the first line of the documentation for each function/class.

```
lookfor(searchString)
```

If you want to search the entire help comment block, you'll want to use the `-all` flag

```
lookfor(searchString, '-all')
```

If your search string is only a single word, you can use the [command syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) instead

```
lookfor <search>
lookfor <search> -all
```

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is searching through the documentation without internet, you can use *Help Browser* (shown in the figure) which can be opened by entering [**`doc`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/doc.html) in the command window. You can search any string through your location documentation using it.

[image: Help Browser]

If you use already know the name of the function and want to read its documentation, you can directly use: `doc (function name)` e.g. `doc sum`, it will open the documentation of the `sum` function.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB help, open the "Functions" document. I guess there all of the functions are explained with one sentence.